# Increment by 1 or 2: Loop Speed

Tags: processing-efficiency

I am learning about Embedded Coding on my own and the video I watched said that you could do loop faster if you did two increments in 1 loop then the last increment outside of the loop since it would check the while condition less often.

So my question is, would it be faster to increment by 2 always, and then subtract or add 1 at the end if you exceed your amount.

An example: Let's say I want to perform a method that repeats (i.e. approximate the minimum value of a function by something like newtons method)  Instead of doing newtons method once per loop, we do it twice per loop.  And let's say we want to do it 21 times because we were able to calculate that our method should converge close enough by roughly that many iterations.  Therefore we loop 10x doing it twice per loop, then one last time outside the loop to finish.

Follow up question would be to assume that this is scalable?  i.e. (n+1) times per loop > (n) times per loop + one outside of the loop

Comment: Would this efficiency also work for dynamic coding.  I.e. lets say I make my while loops like :  while( counter < int(array.size()/2)):

Comment: Have a look at [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).